# How can I remove an ID object from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to remove an object from an Array that is stored in a dictionary. I have been able to remove the object by index with this code:

```
[compHandHighValuesArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[highCardDictionary    valueForKey:[cardsShuffled objectAtIndex:1]] intValue]]];
```

However now I want to change [cardsShuffled objectAtIndex:1] to an ID variable. When I replace the code with:

```
[compHandHighValuesArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[highCardDictionary valueForKey:[compCardOneTitle]] intValue]]];
```

I get the error for "expected identifier". What am I missing?

Comment: Although its not the root of your problem, diagnosing it would be easier if this was written using more than one line of code.

Comment: @JonathanArbogast - You are quite correct.  While it may seem "macho" to combine everything into one long statement, eschewing temps, doing so is incredibly hard to understand and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll be sure to include more next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
[highCardDictionary valueForKey:[compCardOneTitle]]
```

isn't valid syntax. I guess that `compCardOneTitle` is your `ID`, but you don't say what an `ID` is...

If `ID` is a string / key, then you should have:

```
[highCardDictionary valueForKey:compCardOneTitle]
```

Comment: ... and use `objectForKey` for dictionaries, not `valueForKey`, unless you need the Key-Value Coding magic.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that but it was a [] issue I was having that was driving me crazy.